# How to start remote celery workers from django

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, worker

I'm trying to use django in combination with celery.

Therefore I came across `autodiscover_tasks()` and I'm not fully sure on how to use them. The celery workers get tasks added by other applications (in this case a node backend).

So far I used this to start the worker:

```
celery worker -Q extraction --hostname=extraction_worker
```

which works fine.

Now I'm not sure what the general idea of the django-celery integration is. Should workers still be started from external (e.g. with the command above), or should they be managed and started from the django application?

My celery.py looks like:

```
# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'main.settings')

app = Celery('app')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

then I have 2 apps containing a tasks.py file with:

```
@shared_task
def extraction(total):
    return 'Task executed'
```

how can I now register django to register the worker for those tasks?

Comment: what do you mean by django-celery integration

Comment: maybe it is missleading. Basically using celery with django, as described in https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html

Comment: just checking out as there was package django-celery prior to celery version 3.1 which was integration point not needed anymore

Comment: Also i would think you would get more clear about process if you go to https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/next-steps.html#next-steps

Comment: Ok after some reading I realized that I need to start through the celery command and not through the application itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just start worker process as [documented](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html#starting-the-worker-process), you don't need to register anything else

> In a production environment you’ll want to run the worker in the
>   background as a daemon - see Daemonization - but for testing and
>   development it is useful to be able to start a worker instance by
>   using the celery worker manage command, much as you’d use Django’s
>   manage.py runserver:
>
> ```
> celery -A proj worker -l info
> ```
>
> For a complete listing of the command-line options available, use the
>   help command:
>
> ```
> celery help
> ```

celery worker collects/registers task when it runs and also consumes tasks which it found out